# Linq Group VS Join+Into

Tags: c#, linq

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем преимущество использования в Linq запросе комбинации `Join+Into` перед `group`. Что один, что второй используются для группировки сходных по определенных критериев объектов в массив. Однако зачем использовать `Join+Into` если, все сортировочные критерии есть и так в нужном массиве. Например есть две последовательности:

```
        List<int> type = new List<int>()
        {
            1,2,3,4
        };
        List<Tov> classes = new List<Tov>()
        {
            new Tov(4, "Велосипед"),
            new Tov(1, "Автомобиль"),
            new Tov(2, "Катер"),
            new Tov(4, "Мопед"),
            new Tov(3, "Самолет"),
            new Tov(2, "Лодка"),
            new Tov(1, "Самосвал"),
            new Tov(4, "Самокат"),
            new Tov(2, "Корабль"),
        };
```

В чем преимущество, например этого запроса

```
        var v = from t in classes
                group t by t.id;
```

От этого :

```
    var v = from t in type
            join cl in classes
            on t equals cl.id
            into Mass
            select new { Type = t, Mass };
```

Ведь в результате мы все равно как в первом так и во втором случае получим набор из массивов где объекты  определены по одному признаку. И есть ли такой пример, где невозможно воспользоваться одним способом, зато можно другим ? Спасибо.

Comment: А ничего, что ты во втором запросе используешь дополнительную сущность в виде захардкоженного списка ключей всех групп?

Comment: Я это понимаю, вопрос ведь в том, что если нужно сформировать по какому-то критерию массивы, то зачем тогда вообще нужен  второй поток данных, если все эти критерии и так содержаться в исходном массиве. Как в моем примере, ведь можно вообще обойтись без массива type

Comment: Прошу прощения, немного перемудрил. В моем ответе, во втором случае, `DefaultIfEmpty` даже не нужен. Там и так вернется пустой список. Я скорректировал ответ, чтобы не вводить в лишнее заблуждение.

Comment: Все равно спасибо большое. Главное я суть понял. А то не мог понять почему join+into посвящен целый раздел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group by` - это аггрегация данных, т.е. результат будет содержать столько же или меньше (в случае повтороения значений) строк.
`Join` - это содениение данных, т.е. результат будет содержать столько же и никак не меньше строк.

Если в список `type` будут повторяющиеся значения, то результат второго запроса поменяется. Для такого списка:

```
var type = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 , 2, 1 };
```

Второй запрос вернет семь строк, а не 4 как первый.

[DotNetFiddle пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/euXcos)

---

В другом случае, когда не для каждого значения `id` из списка `type` будут существовать соответствующие значения в списке `classes` - во втором запросе, для каждого такого значения `id` из списка `type` вернется пустой список значений из `classes`.

[DotNetFiddle пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3O8jr)

Answer (score 2):

Пример, когда один сработает, а другой - нет. Немного модифицируем исходные данные, а именно - уберем из классов тип 3: `new Tov(3, "Самолет")`:

```
List<int> type = new List<int>()
{
    1,2,3,4
};
List<Tov> classes = new List<Tov>()
{
    new Tov(4, "Велосипед"),
    new Tov(1, "Автомобиль"),
    new Tov(2, "Катер"),
    new Tov(4, "Мопед"),
    new Tov(2, "Лодка"),
    new Tov(1, "Самосвал"),
    new Tov(4, "Самокат"),
    new Tov(2, "Корабль"),
};
```

Первый запрос вернет только те типы, которые есть в classes - 1,2,4. Второй - все типы. В т.ч. и тип 3, для которого ни одного класса нет.
Что применять - зависит от целей. Например, нужно проверить что у всех типов есть хотя бы один класс. Тогда нам не подойдет первый запрос.
А если в `type` будут не уникальные данные - нам не подойдет второй запрос, если нужно избежать "задвоения" данных. Так что по ситуации.